# android application that should not be interfere by other application.

Tags: android

i want to make android application and that application should not be uninstalled and no other application should be installed, and when phone starts this application should launch.
Is it Possible?
And sorry if i ask a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make a custom ROM.

Start here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195858

Comment: i saw your link to make a custom ROM, so by doing this may i give all the privileges like install application, uninstall and no other application can install?